# What's a "safe" way of installing a Debian package that isn't in backports?

Tags: debian, packages

I want to grab [nginx 0.8.x](http://nginx.org/download/nginx-0.8.52.tar.gz) but I realize that 0.7 is in [Lenny-backports](http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/nginx). How can I "safely" install it so that maybe in the future if I decide to download a newer release from aptitude, it doesn't mess up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a package for 0.8.x somewhere, then you can try grabbing the source package and building it.  With an appropriate `deb-src` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` it should be as easy as `apt-get build-dep nginx; apt-get source -b nginx`

It looks like even sid is on 0.7.x, though, but [this person](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1105902) has a guide to building a package from 0.8.x in Ubuntu which should work the same way on Lenny as long as the required libraries are installed.

If you can't find a package pre-built for your distribution then building the package from source is the best way to be sure that the package is compatible with the libraries on your system.